# Set AES key in iOS from a byte array

Tags: ios, cryptography, aes, secret-key

My service gives me a key as a byte array. For example：

```
(byte) 0x16, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xAB, (byte) 0xEA, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xA7,(byte) 0xD4, (byte) 0xE5, (byte) 0x2F, (byte) 0x7F, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x4C, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x7D,
```

In iOS, the AES key is a string. I am trying to use this byte array as a key in iOS.

Comment: I've flagged this on the grounds that it's very unclear what you're asking. What are you even trying to achieve here?

Comment: Can you make your question readable and understandable? For now I can't  guess what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Dev4Anker I've edited your question so that it is at least readable. Can you give an example of what you tried and what the error was that you received? Also, are you using Objective-C or Swift? Please [edit] the question yourself to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

this OC code ------

//Encrypt AES  NOPadding
-(NSData *)AES128Encrypt{

```
NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
//  Encrypt Key
Byte keybyte[]={0x77,0x24,0x56,0xf2,0xa7,0x66,0x4c,0xf3,0x39, 0x2c,0x35,0x97,0xe9,0x3e,0x57,0x47};
NSData *keyData=[[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:keybyte length:16];
const void *vKey = (const void *)[keyData bytes];
//Encrypt Iv
Byte ivbyte[]={0x24,0x4e,0x6d,0x8a,0x56,0xac,0x87,0x91,
    0x24,0x43,0x2d,0x8b,0x6c,0xbc,0xa2,0xc4};
NSData *IvData=[[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:ivbyte length:16];
const void *vIv = (const void *)[IvData bytes];


CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      0x0000,
                                      vKey,
                                      kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                      vIv,
                                      [self bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}
free(buffer);
return nil;
```

}